# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me aparezca los datos?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una base de datos mediante PHP tengo todo funcionando perfectamente la única cosa que no me sale es cuando introduzco un DNI para modificarlo quiero que la imagen me aparezca y pueda ver cual es la imagen que tengo seleccionada

```
<td class="esp">Seleciona una Foto:</td>
            <td ><input type="file" name="foto" value="<?php
            $dni=$_POST["dni"];
            $consulta="select Foto from jugadores where Dni='$dni'";
            $filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
                foreach($filas as $fila) {
                     echo "<img class='ins' src='".$fila["Foto"]."'></img>";
                    
                }
            ?>"/></td>
```

Y cuando voy a modificar no me aparece nada. Sin embargo, los datos anteriores si me aparecen.

Aquí muestro una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis comprobar en la parte de la fecha de nacimiento y la categoría si me aparece pero la fotografía no.

He seguido el mismo patrón para todo ya que fecha nacimiento y categoría lo e puesto as.

```
<tr>
        <td class="esp">Fecha de Nacimiento:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nacimiento" size="40px" value="<?php
            $dni=$_POST["dni"];
            $consulta="select FechaNacimiento from jugadores where Dni='$dni'";
            $filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
                foreach($filas as $fila) {
                     echo $fila["FechaNacimiento"];
                    }
            ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="esp">Categoria:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="categoria" size="40px" value="<?php
            $dni=$_POST["dni"];
            $consulta="select Categoria from jugadores where Dni='$dni'";
            $filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
                foreach($filas as $fila) {
                     echo $fila["Categoria"];
                    }
            ?>"/></td>
```

O sea que si el DNI es correcto me muestre todo los datos pero la imagen no logro hacer que me la muestre.

Comment: Pon un `echo $fila["Foto"];` y revisa lo que imprime y si ese archivo realmente existe, suponiendo que imprime una ruta. Por otra parte, tampoco dices lo que imprime el código en esa parte. Cuando una foto no es encontrada imprime un cuadro en blanco con un signo de `?` en el centro o algo por el estilo. No veo nada parecido en tu captura de pantalla. ¿Dónde está la salida de tu código?

Comment: Pero esque tampoco me muestra el signo ?, ademas en los datos anteriores si me muestra los datos introducidos, y en esa parte lo que quiero es que me aparezca la imagen que ya esta introducida en la base de datos

Comment: En un campo `input type="file"` no te va a mostrar un valor default y menos la imagen. Es más, esos campos son [bastante jodidos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696884/1545868) Lo que podrías hacer es un input radio con las imágenes actuales y el uploader para una nueva foto.

Comment: Creo que se están mezclando dos cosas aquí: por un lado no se estaría mostrando la ruta de la imagen, es lo que yo interpreto que quieres lograr al intentar crear un elemento `img`, por otro lado está el input tipo file que menciona @aeportugal. Te sugerí que mostrarás un `echo` de la supuesta ruta de la imagen. ¿Lo hiciste? ¿Muestra algo? Por ejemplo, tú estás trabajando con un elemento `table` de HTML y por una tontería como que esa table no esté bien hecha (tr, td u otros elementos de más o de menos) ciertas cosas no se mostrarían. **Por eso te sugerí que depures con un `echo`**.

Comment: Si amigo e conseguido que me aparezca el Nombre pero yo quiero que me salga como en el ejemplo que he publicado abajo. Es lo que no consigo hacer es para un proyecto que estoy realizando y quiero quedarlo como en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que quiero es que me quede una cosa asi como este ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis me aparece la imagen y luego aparece el selecciona foto